# Deferred shading in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, deferred

I've got a strange problem with my deferred shading implementation.
I render the required information via MRT into a FBO, currently diffuse, position and normals in world space, which looks like this:

[image]

This is done with the following setup for all tree textures:

```
diffuse = std::shared_ptr<bb::Texture>(new bb::Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D)); // generates texture ID
diffuse->bind();
diffuse->texture2D(0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0); // glTexture2D
diffuse->parameterf(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
diffuse->parameterf(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
diffuse->parameterf(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
diffuse->parameterf(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
diffuse->unbind();
texture2D(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+1, diffuse->getID(), 0);
```

These are then used in my drawing stage:

```
dsShader->bind();
dsShader->enableVertexAttribArrays();

ds->diffuse->bind(GL_TEXTURE0); // "ds" is an FBO containing the textures
ds->position->bind(GL_TEXTURE0+1);
ds->normal->bind(GL_TEXTURE0+2);

dsShader->sendUniform("diffuse", 0);
dsShader->sendUniform("position", 1);
dsShader->sendUniform("normal", 2);

dsShader->sendUniform("camera", camera3D->position.x, camera3D->position.y, camera3D->position.z);

dsOut->indexBuffer->bind();
dsOut->vertex2Buffer->bind();
dsOut->vertex2Buffer->vertexAttribPointer(dsShader->getAttribLocation("vertex0"), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, dsOut->indexBuffer->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

ds->diffuse->unbind();
ds->position->unbind();
ds->normal->unbind();

dsShader->disableVertexAttribArrays();
dsShader->unbind();
```

With the following shader (just the necessary part, the light source is hardcoded):

```
struct DirLight{
    vec3 direction;
    vec4 diffuse, specular;
};

uniform sampler2D diffuse;
uniform sampler2D position;
uniform sampler2D normal;

uniform vec3 camera;

DirLight light0 = DirLight(vec3(1, 1, 0), vec4(0.3), vec4(0.1));

in vec2 vertex;

void main(){
    vec4 color = texture(diffuse, vertex)*0.5;
    vec3 p = vec3(texture(position, vertex));
    vec3 n = normalize(vec3(texture(normal, vertex)));

    float ndotl = max(dot(n, normalize(light0.direction)), 0.0); // simple phong

    if(ndotl > 0.0){
        color += ndotl*light0.diffuse;
    }

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The wierd part is, if I set the light source direction to negative values, lets say:

```
DirLight light0 = DirLight(vec3(-1, 0, 0), vec4(0.3), vec4(0.1));
```

The final result is not shaded. It looks right for positive values (more or less).
Here is a picture of the output:

[image]

And there could also be a problem with the normals, marked in the red area.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your normals.  Have you tried rendering the scene, without deferred shading?

Comment: Yep I tried that, no problem. You can see the output of all tree textures in the first picture. Something I forgot to mention is that my z-axis is the upper axis.

Comment: It looks like your normals are reversed, in the first one.  I would suggest trying to fix that, first, then coming back and testing the negative values, again.

Comment: No I don't think so. If I inverse them most of the normal map is black. And I tested the geometry in blender, the normals face to the outside. But there could be a problem with my calculation? Currently I multiply each normal with the inversed, transposed model matrix.

Comment: Here is a larger picture of the normal map: [click](http://marvinblum.de/files/Screenshots/ds_normals_buggy.png)

Comment: What is the format of your normal G-Buffer? In your attached screenshot, you have neglected to scale and bias the normals into the visible color range... that is to say, any normal that has a negative value is clipped by GL when displayed on the default framebuffer simply to black. If you are trying to store the normals in a format like `GL_RGB` then the G-Buffer itself also has this behavior. You can either use something like `GL_RGB8_SNORM` or do the old `* 0.5 + 0.5` to manually scale into [0,1] and `* 2.0 - 1.0` trick to  scale back to [-1,1].

Comment: Make sure you do this at the very least when it comes time to visualize the normals. They will be false colored, since negative colors are meaningless, but a trained eye knows that values between 0.0 and 0.5 in a normal G-Buffer are negative and > 0.5 is postive.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and let you know :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Your solution seems to have worked for the OP. You should consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the solution by Andon M. Coleman works, I switched the internal format to GL_RGB8_SNORM.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Since this appeared in the flag review queue, here is a note for reviewers: This actually *is* an answer, not a "thank you". There are no other answers currently posted for this question. The answer was suggested in question comments and the OP has helpfully summarized it here. @user3476897: Suggest accepting Andon's answer if he decides to post an answer.